How to see successive contraction of gates in a DAG Circuit
I have a circuit and I want to see the DAG graph at each step of a series of contraction until I get to the unitary matrix of the circuit, I put together some code that should accomplish this, but clearly I made some mistakes as I cannot understand what to put into wires maps, nor if the problem is related to that
Below the code:
# do successive contraction until I have the unitary matrix and display all the intermediate graphs along the way
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator

def successive_contraction(dag):
    while len(dag.op_nodes()) > 1:
        node_block = dag.op_nodes()[:2]  # Take the first two nodes as a block
        op1 = Operator(node_block[0].op)
        op2 = Operator(node_block[1].op)
        unitary = op1 ^ op2  # Tensor product of the two operators
        dag.replace_block_with_op(node_block, unitary, {})
        dag_drawer(dag)  # Display the intermediate graph

successive_contraction(dag)

